# Preview Images using fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to preview 3 images which I have taken on same page using FileUpload.I have to also show 3 thumbnail of it each 3 images.But problem is it shows first images 9 times i.e 3*3 . I create image folder for it .here is code which I have run:
 string file, thumbPath;

```
    file = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    thumbPath = ("~/images" + "/" + file);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/") + file);
    Image1.ImageUrl = thumbPath;
    Image2.ImageUrl = thumbPath;
    Image3.ImageUrl = thumbPath;

    file = FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName;
    thumbPath = ("~/images" + "/" + file);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/") + file);
    Image4.ImageUrl = thumbPath;
    Image5.ImageUrl = thumbPath;
    Image6.ImageUrl = thumbPath;

    file = FileUpload3.PostedFile.FileName;
    thumbPath = ("~/images" + "/" + file);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/") + file);
    Image7.ImageUrl = thumbPath;
    Image8.ImageUrl = thumbPath;
    Image9.ImageUrl = thumbPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saving the first image every time, so it makes sense why you're seeing that image everywhere.  This same line occurs 3 times in your code:

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/") + file);
```

You probably want to vary the `FileUpload1` so that you also use `FileUpload2` and `FileUpload3` in the second and third sections of your code.

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/") + file);
// do something
FileUpload2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/") + file);
// do something
FileUpload3.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/") + file);
// do something
```

Also, it seems like if the user chooses to upload multiple files of the same name, you'll overwrite some of them. You should probably use some unique filenames (perhaps windows tempfiles). Don't use the name of the file that the user uploaded, or at least not for this specific task.

Answer (score 0):

problem in your code in this line

```
       FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/") + file);
```

try this

```
       string  file = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
       string thumbPath = ("~/images" + "/" + file);            
       FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/"+ file) );
       Image1.ImageUrl = thumbPath;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this below Code for single image you can change it for multiple images also:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">

    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        #newPreview 
        { 
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(sizingMethod=scale);

        } 
    </style> 


    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function PreviewImg(imgFile) 
    { 
        var newPreview = document.getElementById("newPreview"); 
        newPreview.filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = imgFile.value;

        newPreview.style.width = "80px"; 
        newPreview.style.height = "60px"; 
    } 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div> 
        preview 
        <asp:FileUpload ID="Fud_Pic" runat="server"
 onchange="PreviewImg(this)" />

        <div id="newPreview">

        </div> 
    </div> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```